# How do i make a table of unknown number of rows and columns in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

How do i create a `table` of unknown number of rows and columns in my `UITableViewCell` ? I am creating a survey application and the reporting can contain matrix type questions aswell. How do i view those in my TableViewCell. if the number of rows and columns exceed, it should also use scrolling to display the content. below is the picture of how it looks like. [image] also this app is for iPhone and iPad both so the answer should be kept in consideration of `Auto Layouts`.

**EDIT**

The red crosses should also be in my control as i need to display a tick where the user has ticked.

Comment: Why a table view and not a collection view?

Comment: @Wain because i am displaying the whole list of question in my TableView. Section header containing the question and the number of cells showing the options (answers). so i need to implement this in a `tableView's Cell`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inserted a `UIScrollView` in the `TableView's Cell` and created the rows and columns dynamically using for loops on the basis of the number of rows and columns. Created dynamic labels for columns and rows and imageViews for tick and crosses and kept on managing the size by using x and y and at the end set the scrollView's content according to x and y for the scrolling.